# How to communicate android application with spring server

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, spring, rest

I have an WebPage running on an Apache Tomcat v7.0 Server, which communicates with an MySQL database. This is perfectly running with Spring MVC 3.0.5. Now I'm developing an Android App and I want it to communicate with the created MySQL database. I know I can't do it directly, so I'm thinking to do it through my Tomcat server. But what's the best way to do it? Could you give me any directions or tutorials? I've read some articles about RESTful.. but how do I integrate it with Spring?

Comment: Search for "Spring REST".  Implement a REST server.  Access the REST server from your android applcation

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your question is too large to answer in detail,  but here are some useful hints:

- Jackson Mapper (Maps Java --> JSON --> JAVA)
- android-async-http (a good library to do requests on android)
- Configure the Jackson Mapper in Spring and write a controller method with `@RequestBody` `@ResponseBody`

Alternatively you could use SQLite if you don't need to store it on the server.